NextJS, PagedJS and Puppeteer: PDF Cross references jump to wrong page
I generate my dynamic webpage including table of contents with NextJS and Paged. On browser with HTML page, all works well including listing page numbers on table of contents and navigating to the respective chapter by clicking on TOC items. I use Puppeteer to export the page to PDF. In the exported PDF, the links jump ahead by couple of pages. Has anyone faced this issue? At the moment, I am not sure if this is a Puppeteer issue or what I am trying to do (cross refernce in PDF) is just not possible in HTML to PDF workflow.  Thank you.

Please share a [mcve].

Turned out to be a Chromium issue. Here is the bug report if anyone comes looking for an answer https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/12601
